# Angular 4: Component disappears after injecting Service

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

I got a problem regarding `Components` and `Services` in `Angular 4`.
So I got the `CustomerComponent`:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-customer',
templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./customer.component.css']
})
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {

customers: Customer[] = [];
constructor() { }
```

And the `Customer Model`:

```
export class Customer {
constructor(
public id: number,
public firstName: string,
public lastName: string
) {  }
}
```

And the `CustomerService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomerService {

private customersUrl = 'http://localhost:9090/customer';
constructor(private http: Http) { }

// Get all customers
getCustomers(): Promise<Customer[]> {
return this.http.get(this.customersUrl)
  .toPromise()
  .then(response => response.json() as Customer[])
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Right now i want to display the CustomerComponent in the AppComponent.
Which works by adding `<app-customer></app-customer>` it displays: `customer works`.

But when I'm adding the `CustomerService` into the Constructor of the `CustomerComponent` like this:

```
 constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) { }
```

The `customer works` doesnt get displayed anymore and i don't get an error message in the console. So I don't know what the problem is. Could somebody help here? Thanks

Comment: Do you have a compilation error in your terminal, where you (probably) execute ng serve? Which console are you talking about? If you're talking about the terminal, have you checked the browser console?

Comment: Could you add your customer.html to the question

Comment: better check for any error in the browser console. On chrome, right click -> inspect -> console tab.

Comment: @JBNizet  I'm talking about both, the one where i am running ng serve and the browser console. Both don't show an error.

Comment: @IzzoObella I'm talking about both, the one where i am running ng serve and the browser console. Both don't show an error.

Comment: can you create a simple Plunker\StackBlitz example reproducing your problem?

Comment: @IzzoObella The only thing my html shows by now is "customer works!"

Comment: Honestly you have no error in the web console or ng serve console

Comment: I found out what the problem was. I forgot to import the HttpModule in the AppModule. But i still don't know why i didn't see an error anywhere... Thanks for your help guys @IzzoObella

Comment: run npm start in the terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. I forgot to import the `HttpModule` in the `AppModule`. But i still don't know why i didn't see an error anywhere...

Comment: That would definitely print an error in the console. Have you configured it to filter out some types of messages? Have you tested with a different browser?

Comment: @JBNizet I found out that the error/errors appear for like a 1/10 of a secound in the chrome browser console. After that the console is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Add your service to app module.

```
providers: [
    CustomerService
  ],
```